# GLSL: is it possible to create mask of one-colored area which contains central pixel?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, flood-fill

I want to create effect like "Magic Wand" in Photoshop for central pixel of screen with GLSL shaders in my iPhone app (capturing image from camera). Now I've made this by getting array of pixels and applying some sort of flood-fill algorithm for central pixel (all with Objective-C code). This is performed on CPU and this is a bit too slow for me, so I want to try to make it with GLSL shaders.

Actually, all I need is to rewrite flood-fill in fragment shader, more precisely speaking, to know if current fragment's color is near threshold color and if current fragment is the neighbor of previously detected fragments that are in area. That sounds too confusing for me and I can not understand if it is even possible.

The algorithm for flood-fill is (pseudocode):

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. Set Q to the empty queue.
 2. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 3. Add node to Q.
 4. For each element n of Q:
 5.     If the color of n is equal to target-color:
 6.         Set w and e equal to n.
 7.         Move w to the west until the color of the node to the west of w no longer matches target-color.
 8.         Move e to the east until the color of the node to the east of e no longer matches target-color.
 9.         Set the color of nodes between w and e to replacement-color.
10.         For each node n between w and e:
11.             If the color of the node to the north of n is target-color, add that node to Q.
12.             If the color of the node to the south of n is target-color, add that node to Q.
13. Continue looping until Q is exhausted.
14. Return.
```

The question: is it possible to do that in shader, and if yes, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, shaders do not work that way. In shaders you always can only have read OR write, not both at the same time. If you look back at you algorithm it does read AND write on the same data.

You could try a ping pong scheme, but I doubt it would be fast:

```
for ( sometime )
  for (every pixel in dest) 
    if source has filled neighbours (up,left,top,bottom) and is above threshold, then write fill
    else write source
  flip source and dest
```

this will step one pixel more per iteration - but you have only an upper limit on when it is done (the image size).

You could go even more clever and try to do some pyramid scheme: Run at 2x lower resolutions first and use that to determine areas in the fill. But it is really just not an algorithm that works well on the GPU. I recommend doing a hand optimized assembly CPU version instead.

Comment: I was expecting that.. I will follow your advice and try to optimize that on CPU, since I am not sure if result will be good, thanks for answer!

Comment: Mike Ash has two posts on implementing and optimizing flood fill that might be of interest to you: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-09-14-implementing-a-flood-fill.html http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-09-28-optimizing-flood-fill.html

Comment: Good link! Thanks for adding it - sorry I can not upvote comments. But now you got me thinking about flood fills again. Such a simple and easy to watch algorithm. Easy to get the worst case test. And really hard to put on a GPU.

Comment: "I recommend doing a hand optimized assembly CPU version instead.". No, please, no. This will kill your performance in the worst case and be a headache to write in the best. Just write ordinary code.

Comment: To clarify: It does not need to be assembly. But as he is looking for speed this is one of the algorithms very worth understanding at the instruction level. Especially when starting out from Obj-C.